# What is the JRE parameter-XX:HeapBaseMinAddress for and what should I set it to?

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, out-of-memory

I was running inspect code in IntelliJ 2021.2.3 on my top-level source directory. IntelliJ crashed after a few minutes with `insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 1204496 bytes for Chunk::new`. I am running on Windows10, IntelliJ was configured with 4096MB, and I have 32GB of free RAM.

One of the suggested solutions is using -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress to "place the java heap above 32GB". How would this free up memory for the JRE and how do I figure what minimum address to set it to?

Comment: Are you even running a 64-bit JVM?

Comment: If the issue persists with 2021.3 release, please report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs and the memory snapshot attached (`java_error_in_idea.hprof` in the user's home directory). You don't need to change any other options except `-Xmx`. Large files can be uploaded at https://uploads.jetbrains.com.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Will do.